# Pandas multi-index and map two separate dictionaries

Tags: pandas, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I'll do my best to explain my issue. I have a DataFrame with several columns and 8780 rows for each hour of the year. Each row contains :

```
day   work   hour   ...etc
1      0      0
1      0      1
1      0      2
  ...
3      1      0
3      1      1
  ...
3      1      23
```

Two columns 'work' with 0's and 1's and 'hour' with numbers from 00-23. I want to create new column with specific groups for hours like:

```
hour_work = {0:2, 1:2, 
        2:1, 3:1, 4:1, 5:1, 6:1,  
        7:3, 8:3, 
        9:4, 10:4, 11:4,  
        12:5,
        13:4, 14:4, 15:4, 16:4,
        17:3, 18:3, 19:3, 20:3, 21:3, 
        22:1, 23:1}

hour_notwork = {0:2, 1:2, 
        2:1, 3:1, 4:1, 5:1, 6:1,  
        7:3, 8:3,   
        9:4, 10:4, 11:4,  
        12:5, 13:5,
        14:4, 15:4, 16:4, 17:3, 18:3, 19:3, 
        20:2, 21:2, 22:2, 23:2
        }
```

I need to create a new column that will map both dictionaries based on if it's working or not working day(0, 1) for each hour after groupby (or maybe not) 'work' and 'hour':

```
df['hour_group'] = df.groupby(['work', 'hour']).apply(work_func). #where in work is 1
df['hour_group'] = df.groupby(['work', 'hour']).apply(not_work_func). #where in work is 0
```

desired output should look like(with the new column created based on work, hour and two dictionaries) :

```
day    work  hour    hour_group
1      0      0       2
1      0      1       2
1      0      2       1
1      0      3       1
1      0      4       1
1      0      5       1
1      0      6       1
1      0      7       3
1      0      8       3
1      0      9       4
1      0      10      4
1      0      11      4
1      0      12      5
1      0      13      4
1      0      14      4
1      0      15      4
1      0      16      4
1      0      17      3
1      0      18      3
1      0      19      3
1      0      20      3
1      0      21      2
1      0      22      2
1      0      23      2

....   

3      1     0       2
3      1     1       2
3      1     2       2
3      1     3       1
3      1     4       1
3      1     5       1
3      1     6       1
3      1     7       3
3      1     8       3
3      1     9       3
3      1     10      3
3      1     11      3
3      1     12      4
3      1     13      4
3      1     14      4
3      1     15      4
3      1     16      5
3      1     17      5
3      1     18      3
3      1     19      3
3      1     20      3
3      1     21      2
3      1     22      2
3      1     23      1
```

Comment: Can you show , what is the expected output ?

Comment: the last example is my expected output mate

Comment: `df=pd.DataFrame({'hour_work':list(hour_work.values()),'hour_notwork':list(hour_notwork.values()),'hour':list(hour_work.keys())})` then
`pd.melt(df,'hour').set_index('variable')`

Comment: well not as expected mate, my dataframe have other columns(features). So I'm looking for some grouping only by 'work' and 'hour' to map to dictionaries base on work value if is 1- map hours from 0-23 with hour_work dict and all maps in same new column. Maybe an if statement, dunoo :(

Comment: if more data is involved, provide a more thorough explanation and example

Comment: you are right mate, edit my original post, hope it's little more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my question:

```
df.loc[(df['work'] == 1) & df['hour'].isin([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),['hindex']] = 1
df.loc[(df['work'] == 1) & df['hour'].isin([7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]), ['hindex']] = 2
df.loc[(df['work'] == 1) & df['hour'].isin([17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]), ['hindex']] = 3

df.loc[(df['work'] == 0) & df['hour'].isin([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), ['hindex']] = 1
df.loc[(df['work'] == 0) & df['hour'].isin([7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]), ['hindex']] = 2
df.loc[(df['work'] == 0) & df['hour'].isin([17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]), ['hindex']] = 3
```